# Где скачать Perl v.1?

Tags: perl

Дайте пожалуйста ссылку на perl v.1. Хочу установить, и поизучать.

Comment: Чисто из интереса: зачем? Последняя версия аж 5.28. И вообще имхо устаревший и почти не используемый язык...

Comment: Последняя, аж 5.29) И вообще не устаревший, и много где используемый.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/source/RCLAMP/perl-1.0_16/README

Comment: https://www.cpan.org/src/

Comment: Где?)) Насколько я знаю он обычно используется для мелких однострочных скриптов как альтернатива башу. Серьезных продуктов на нем раз два и обчелся.

Comment: @DarkByte, дадад

Comment: @DarkByte например [OTRS](https://otrs.com/) - единственная servicedesk-платформа сертифицированная как ITIL® V3 compliant.

Comment: @DarkByte Не обращали внимания, что yandex периодически ищет perl программистов, для себя ... А еще amazon например (у них все на perl) ... У сотовых операторов часто используется. Генетики вообще почти все на нем.

Comment: @DarkByte если вы чуть-чуть отойдёте от веб-программирования и винды (особенно в сторону парсинга данных и администрирования), то ВНЕЗАПНО увидите :)

Comment: @DarkByte На Perl  почти ВСЕ вертится в *nix сообществах, язык востребованный как рабочий среди технарей, энергетиков , часто используется в генетике http://circos.ca/ и накопил огромный архив уже готовых решений для других технических отраслей https://www.cpan.org/

Answer (score 0):

Вот, кому интересно, нашёл: https://bitbucket.org/chastai/perl-1.0

Для установки Perl v.1 выполните следующие шаги:

`apt-get install byacc` or `dnf install byacc`

1: `git clone https://bitbucket.org/chastai/perl-1.0.git`

2: `cd perl-1.0`

3: `./Configure -d`

4: `make`

Смотрим версию и насладжаемся:

`./perl -v`

> $Header: perly.c,v 1.0.1.11 88/03/10 16:42:59 root Exp $
>
> Patch level: 29

Answer (score 0):

Думаю верней будет - зайти на сайт копьюнити, скачать гит репозиторий и перейти к тегу 1.0

Ссылка на этот тэг

https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/8d063cd8450e59ea1c611a2f4f5a21059a2804f1

и скомпилировать.